# Ajax & niceSelect()

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using niceSelect on my select menus which are working fine.

I'm using Ajax to add a second select menu (county) based on the first select selection (region)

it all works apart from I can't seem to get the niceSelect to apply to the new drop down in #regionHolder ? My HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 column-lg-full">
<div class="input-box">
<label class="label-text">Location</label>
<div class="form-group">
<select class="location-option-field" id="jobRegion" name="jobRegion">
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
    <option value="region-1">Region 1</option>
    <option value="region-2">Region 2</option>
    <option value="region-3">Region 3</option>
</select>
</div><!-- end form-group -->
</div>
</div><!-- end col-lg-4 -->
                                        
<div class="col-lg-4 column-lg-full" id="regionHolder"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready( function () {
             
             $('select').niceSelect();
             
             $(".column-lg-full").on('change', "#jobRegion", function(event) {
                
                event.preventDefault();
                var value = $("#jobRegion option:selected").val();

                $.ajax({
                  url: '/control/employer/jobs/region',
                  type: "GET",
                  data: { "region" : value },       
                  success: function(result) {
                      console.log(result);
                      $("#regionHolder").html(result);
                  },
                    cache: false
                });
                 
            });
             
         });
```

Console log:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 column-lg-full" id="regionHolder">
<div class="input-box">
<label class="label-text">County</label>
<div class="form-group">
<select class="location-option-field" id="jobCounty" name="jobCounty">
<option value="">Select Region</option>
</select>
</div><!-- end form-group -->
</div>
</div><!-- end col-lg-4 -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After typing all of that I then solved it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/control/employer/jobs/region',
    type: "GET",
    data: { "region" : value },     
    success: function(result) {
        $("#regionHolder").html(result).find('#jobCounty').niceSelect();
    },
    cache: false
});
```